# Comparing topologies with subbases

Tags: general-topology

There is the following theorem useful for comparison of topologies

> If $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}′$ are bases for topologies $\tau, \tau′$ on $X$, then $\tau \subset \tau′$ if and only if for each $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x \in B$, there is a $B′ \in \mathcal{B}'$such that $x \in B′ \subset B$.

Now is there something like this for subbases instead of bases? It would be probably helpful to have something like this if we're comparing product topologies? The subbase consits of preimages $\pi_{i}^{-1} (U_i)$ such that $U_i$ open in $X_i$ it's easier to work with these instead of the finit intersections of these sets.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is $\pi_i$?

Comment: It is the projection $\pi_i : X \to X_i$ for $X$ being the product space.

Comment: You don’t have to compare product topologies: **the** product topology is unique.

Answer (score 0):

> If $\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{S}′$ are subbases for topologies $\tau, \tau′$ on $X$, then $\tau \subseteq \tau′$ if and only if for each $S \in \mathcal{S}$ and $x \in S$, there are finitely many $S_1,\ldots, S_n  \in \mathcal{S}'$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{1=1}^n S_i \subseteq S$.

is the closed equivalent, I think...